# ¿Cómo puedo coger un elemento aleatorio de un array?

Tags: array, bash

Deseo hacer un programa que reproduzca un audio aleatoriamente a partir de unos links que asigné como variables...

Aquí mi código:

```
RANGE=3 

echo 

number=$RANDOM 
let "number %= $RANGE" 

ARRAY=(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPKJUzkTt6Y https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jix8bSotZ4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnmEePUXLRs) 
mpv ${ARRAY[$number]}
```

Por cierto, utilizo MPV como reproductor.

El problema es que quiero que alguno de los links se reproduzcan por medio de MPV, pero me toma la variable como comando y el "mpv" como otro..

```
Code1.sh: line 9: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jix8bSotZ4: No such file or directory
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo corregir el error?

Comment: Quiere escojar al azar o en un orden?

Comment: Al azar es como lo he intentado hacer

Answer (score 3):

[`$RANDOM`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) es una función interna de Bash, que retorna un "pseudorandom" entero en el rango de 0 a 32767. En tu caso, lo que te interesa es generar un número aleatorio de 0 a la longitud del array - 1. Para esto puedes aprovechar la función módulo para obtener el resto de la división por la cantidad de ítems del array. Por ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash

items=("Juan" "Pedro" "Luis" "Laura" "Marcela" "Natalia")

# Obtener un valor random del array
size=${#items[@]}
randomindex=$(($RANDOM % $size))

echo ${items[$randomindex]}
```

Comment: Amigo, me puedes ayudar con el nuevo problema que me surgió? La verdad soy muy nuevo en esto

Comment: @Krypt0NGeek, si es un problema totalmente nuevo, te sugiero crees una nueva pregunta, con gusto te ayudaré en la medida que pueda hacerlo. Saludos.

Comment: No puedo, por alguna razón suspendieron mi cuenta y no puedo realizar preguntas... de todas formas gracias, ya lo resolví. Saludos!!!

Comment: @Krypt0NGeek si te solucionó el problema actual, considera aceptar la respuesta de Patricio.